# UNIX shell script to check the status from oracle table and move the file to appropriate direcoty

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a requirement to loop through sales files in UNIX and then check the status of file in oracle table (status column in svc_posupld_status table) . If the status is C then move the file to "**done**" directory. If the status of file is not C , then move the file to "**reject**" directory
I have written following code

```
for file in `find . -type f -name "POSU*.dat.*" |sort |awk 'gsub("^./","")' | egrep -v "/"`
do
  echo "select reference_id, status from svc_posupld_status where reference_id = '$file'  ;" >>outfile.sql
  echo exit | $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $UP @outfile.sql >> sql.log
done
 - if the status is C then move the file to done directory
 - if the status is NOT C then move the file to reject directory
```

How do I check the status and move files accordingly?

Comment: shell is the wrong language for a task like this.  Pretty nearly any language (with an Oracle sql library) would be a better choice.  I recommend perl, using the [DBI](https://dbi.perl.org/), [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/release/DBD-Oracle), and [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) modules.  The first two will need to be installed (either from packages or with `cpan`, depending on your distro), the last is a perl core module and is included with perl.

Comment: also, what do you want to do when a file isn't in your oracle table?   treat it the same as "status is NOT C" (i.e. move to reject dir), ignore it, or something else?

Comment: finally, instead of looping over each filename and running individual SELECT queries, you'd be better off building a list of quoted filenames separated by commas and iterating over the output of `select reference_id, status from svc_posupld_status where reference_id IN ('file1', 'file2', 'file3', ..., 'fileN');`.

Comment: HI @cas - Thanks for your inputs. We do have Perl installed. However I am not sure how to do this using Perl.  When the file is not in oracle database treat it same as status not in C.

Comment: Hi @Amit, but you also don't know how to do it in a shell script, so I'd recommend learning a bit of Perl (or use some other language that you already know, e.g. Python, Rust, Go, Ruby, Haskell, JavaScript. I'm pretty sure there's bindings for the database of your choice for basically any proper scripting language).